# Convert T-SQL with MIN Function to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

Can you help me to convert SQL to LINQ:

```sql
select empno, dd, Min(sdate) sdate from TransactionPoolView
where sdate >= '" & DateValue(sdate) & "' and sdate < '" & DateValue(edate + 1) 
group by empno, dd
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737926#grpbymin
there is really nice example

Answer (score 0):

There are some SQL to LINQ Converters,You can use

`Linqer` http://www.sqltolinq.com

`LINQPad` http://www.linqpad.net/